# Elegant String getter is possible? How to?

Tags: string, scala

Imagine a text transformation, for example to reduce a Scala String containing Unix path,

```
val thePath = "this/is/a/long/path/Hello.txt"
thePath.replaceAll("^.+/", "")  // reduced to "Hello.txt"
```

My dream (it is not necessary but it is elegant) is to create a general property for all my String datatypes that returns the transformation,

```
thePath.cutPath   // results in "Hello.txt"
```

there are a way to define this implicit method `cutPath` for String datatype (into some scope) with Scala?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is straightforward to implement using an `implicit class`:

```
implicit class myAddOns(s: String) {
  def cutPath = s.replaceAll("^.+/", "")
}

thePath.cutPath // results in "Hello.txt"
```

This effectively adds the `cutPath` method to any `String` value.

Comment: Note the general name of this functionality _(not only in Scala, but on other languages)_ is **extension methods**.

Comment: The [scala-lang.org/core/implicit-classes](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html) is for "advanted users"... For Scala-dummies ideal is something as [scala-2.10-implicit-class-example](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-2.10-implicit-class-example) or ["Pimp my Library"](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=179766)... Do you suggest other (with no marketing advertising) **tutorials**?